# how i can send the issue mule to Jira?

Tags: mule, jira, mule-studio, jira-rest-java-api, jira-rest-api

I am Using mule software for integrate Salesforce with Jira. I want to send Issue Mule to Jira. How i can send the data mule to jira. How i can create the flow to connect with Jira. What are all the object i have to use. the Following flow i create

```
 <jira:config name="Jira" connectionUser="admin" connectionPassword="xxxxxx" connectionAddress="https://company.atlassian.net/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2" doc:name="Jira"/>
<flow name="jira_sampleFlow1" doc:name="jira_sampleFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <jira:create-issue config-ref="Jira"  doc:name="Jira" connectionAddress="https://company.atlassian.net/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2" connectionPassword="******" connectionUser="admin" project="TEST-1" summary="TEST-1" type="TEST-1"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\user\Desktop\FinalCode" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How the Mule Listen other Web Application Data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824790/how-the-mule-listen-other-web-application-data)

Comment: Sending Works fine. At same how can i receive the data in mule from Jira by using Rest API. How can i use the Rest API in mule. Give Simple Example of REST API.