# How the Mule Listen other Web Application Data?

Tags: salesforce, mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-module-jpa

I Want to integrate Salesforce and JIRA by Using Mule. Both are Connecting Properly by using Hard Code. But i want when i am trigger the object in salesforce that time mule accept receive the data of object in salesforce. In Mule Not Listen my salesforce object data. What i do. if the Ip Address is "Localhost" is enough.or must need any realtime URL.The Following code used for recive the account details when i run the local url. instead of i want when i trigger the salesforce i recive the data. Code :

```
    <sfdc:config name="Salesforce" username="xxxxxxxx@gmail.com" password="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" securityToken="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" doc:name="Salesforce">
        <sfdc:connection-pooling-profile initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ONE" exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW"/>
    </sfdc:config>
    <flow name="test_projectFlow1" doc:name="test_projectFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <sfdc:query config-ref="Salesforce" query="select Account from Account" doc:name="Salesforce"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the streaming API to have Mule get notified of changes on Salesforce's side.

See: http://mulesoft.github.io/salesforce-connector/mule/sfdc-config.html#subscribe-topic

Comment: But Condition is should not use Stream API. by using Outbound Message only I should connect with Mule.

Comment: Thanks david its working with Salesforce Streming API. can you suggest me how it will be work instead of streaming API by using SOAP component?